# unexpected behaviour of pre and post increment in c language gcc compiler

Tags: c, output, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

If n has the value 5 then output:

```
printf("%d %d", n++, ++n); //should be 5 and 7
```

But I get as output 6 and 7.

Comment: Please read about rules of sequence points. The behavior is definitely unexpected. You shouldn't change the value of a variable more than 1 time during a function call.

Comment: *unexpected behaviour*  Actually, it's **undefined behaviour**.  The order of evaluation of function arguments is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple unsequenced modifications result to such kind of *Undefined Behavior*. There are tons of results if you search for it, e.g. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior).

Next time compile with all warnings enabled, like this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c:6:22: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'n' [-Wunsequenced]
    printf("%d %d", n++, ++n); 
                     ^   ~~
```

Answer (score 0):

printf() invoke undefined-behavior.
Please have a look at [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

It's not a good practice to modify values of your variables twice or more in a function call argument-list